# How to find a maximum value of two table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to find a maximum  of two table,
for example A table has record.id is primary of A table and B table id is foreign key

```
    Table A
id     |   pos

1            1

2            2
```

and B table has record like

```
id     |   pos

1           1

3           3
```

in this position is 3 is maximum in B table. If A has position higher than B, then need to retrieve A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the max value from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804437/select-the-max-value-from-two-tables)

Comment: Yes Thank you.Below answers also i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union here:

```
SELECT MAX(pos) AS max_value
FROM
(
    SELECT pos FROM TableA UNION ALL
    SELECT pos FROM TableB
) t;
```

If you instead wanted the entire single record corresponding to max `pos` value, then use a `LIMIT` trick:

```
SELECT id, pos, 'TableA' AS tbl FROM TableA UNION ALL
SELECT id, pos, 'TableB' FROM TableB
ORDER BY pos DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine